# Am I missing the point of how a firebase is supposed to work?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this function for adding an asset to a realtime database.

```
 db.ref('assets/' + assetTag).set({
        TagNumber: assetTag,
        Type: assetType,
        Manf: manufacturer,
        Model: model,
        Serial: SN,
        Owner: owner,
        Computer_Name: compName,
        Ram_Ammount: ram 
      });
```

I was under the assumption that the data in this database is stored locally and then backed up to firebase's cloud services. Is this not the case, and if it is, where would I be able to find the json file?

Under the firebase docs it says, "When data is written, it's written to this local version first. ". However, I am unable to find the local version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtime Database doesn't really provide a JSON file.  It's a database that stores data that has a natural JSON representation (objects, arrays, string, numbers, booleans, and null), but you should not think of it as storing "JSON files".

When you call `set()`, when you're doing is writing data to the node in the database that you specify via a Reference object.  The data will be eventually synchronized to Firebase, where it can be read by other clients apps and processes.  If you want to generate a JSON file out of that, you will need to query the database and serialize the results of that query to disk.  Or, you can use the console to export data as JSON.

Comment: Thanks. I was just under the impression that there was a local copy of the data, given that it says that there is a local version written first.

Comment: There is a local cache written first, which is synchronized with the server when the app is online.  There are no downloadable files in that cache - it's purely an implementation detail of the client SDK.